# Examples missing in Qt Creator, OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I've compiled **qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1** on my OS X, and installed a stand alone Qt Creator via **qt-creator-opensource-mac-x86_64-3.6.0.dmg**.

According to [Building and Running an Example's step 1](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-example-application.html), I could see examples in the *Examples* tab in *Welcome* mode, while I got no example over there. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Might take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457017/14583599)